# Reorder a Python list of lists according to the second element of embedded lists

Tags: python

I need to reorder a Python list according to the second element of embedded lists:

So this:

```
[[1, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [3, 'B'], [4, 'A'], [5, 'C']]
```

Should turn into that:

```
[[1, 'A'], [4, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [3, 'B'], [5, 'C']]
```

I am struggling with this piece of code right now:

```
values = set(map(lambda x:x[1], l))
l = [[y[0] for y in l if y[1]==x] for x in values]
```

What the most straightforward way to accomplish this?

Comment: Compared to your current code, which is... what?

Comment: I edited the quesiotn... cheers.

Comment: What does *"struggling with"* mean, exactly? A [mcve] with example inputs and expected and actual outputs is useful.

Comment: You could have found several answers to your question by Googling its exact title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the built-in function [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> l = [[1, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [3, 'B'], [4, 'A'], [5, 'C']]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(l, key=itemgetter(1))
[[1, 'A'], [4, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [3, 'B'], [5, 'C']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
>>> def getKey(item):
...     return item[1]
>>> l = [[1, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [3, 'B'], [4, 'A'], [5, 'C']]
>>> sorted(l, key=getKey)
[[1, 'A'], [4, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [3, 'B'], [5, 'C']]
```

Answer (score 1):

First sort in reverse by the first, and the sort by the second...

```
L = [[1, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [3, 'B'], [4, 'A'], [5, 'C']]
L.sort(key=lambda sublist: sublist[0], reverse=True)
L.sort(key=lambda sublist: sublist[1])
```